# PhP Get Data Not being assigned to Variable

Tags: php, post, get

I am using a PHP to generate a barcode for a small project, however cannot seem to get it to work. I am fairly beginner at PHP and can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Including all required classes
require_once('class/BCGFontFile.php');
require_once('class/BCGColor.php');
require_once('class/BCGDrawing.php');

// Including the barcode technology
require_once('class/BCGcode39.barcode.php');

// Loading Font
$font = new BCGFontFile('./class/font/Arial.ttf', 18);

// The arguments are R, G, B for color.
$color_black = new BCGColor(0, 0, 0);
$color_white = new BCGColor(255, 255, 255);

//$invoice="36";
$drawException = null;
$invoice = $_GET['invoice'];
try {
$code = new BCGcode39();
$code->setScale(2); // Resolution
$code->setThickness(30); // Thickness
$code->setForegroundColor($color_black); // Color of bars
$code->setBackgroundColor($color_white); // Color of spaces
$code->setFont($font); // Font (or 0)
$code->parse($invoice); // Text
} catch(Exception $exception) {
$drawException = $exception;
}
```

The problem is that the line 22 `"$invoice = $_GET['invoice'];"` does not actually pull the get data! if I uncomment the `"//$invoice="36";` and comment out the get section, the code works properly.

Any Ideas?

Comment: try print_r($_GET) or print_r($_REQUEST) to see what values you're actually getting. I'm guessing that there's a typo somewhere. Also, GET variables should be easy to check just by looking at the URL.

Comment: the variable $_GET is in the url?? `test.php?invoice=45`

Comment: I can verify the URL exactly by going to Site.com/tmp/barcodegen.1d-php5.v4.1.0/test.html?invoice=33

Comment: What does `print_r($_GET);` show you? And by the way, why have the HTML file extension for a file containing PHP? You can certainly configure a web server to do that, and apparently you have, but why would you want to do that? :)

Comment: Print_r($_GET); does not output anything at all; its possible because the end result is an image of the entire PhP (a barcode).

Comment: well, figured it out. Sorry for the waste of time, I was putting test.html?invoice=33 in the browser, test.html is an included file with the package. I needed to be using test.PHP?invoice=33 

Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually passing the invoice data in the URL query string? That's what $_GET is for. If you're submitting data from a form, use $_POST instead.

If that doesn't help, try `print_r($_GET)` and make sure that the data is actually being passed the way you expect, and under the right variable name.

Comment: does not work as get or post from a form, both methods result in a "error: no data was entered"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are submitting with GET and not POST? Try doing `print_r($_GET);` and `print_r($_POST);` and see where 'invoice' is.

Comment: I can verify the URL exactly by going to Site.com/tmp/barcodegen.1d-php5.v4.1.0/test.html?invoice=33

Comment: Are you running this on a local server?

Comment: no, currently hosted on a fully functional website that has been running full php solutions (zen cart, interspire) for a long time with no issues.

Comment: If you try `print_r($_GET)`, which you can put just about anywhere in your code (maybe put it right before your `$invoice`?, what is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

trying adding this to the top of your code

```
if(isset($_GET['invoice'])){$invoice = $_GET['invoice']; }else{ echo 'No invoice'; exit;}
```

Comment: nope, entire code stops working, simply displaying the alt tag which is hard-coded "barcode" instead of a dynamic image

Answer (score 0):

IT means you dont sent `invoice` as GET method, you need check for if it exist.

```
$invoice = isset($_GET['invoice']) ? $_GET['invoice'] : 'default invoice';
/*I dont know what is invoice var and its type , but its always good to validate 
   user input*/
if(validInvoice($invoie)) {
  //doStuff
}
```